# Nginx: to show cleaner url on user side

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite url so that on user side they would recive more clraner url.

Server url:

```
https://www.foo.com/news/article/pager.php?blog_id=2&tmpl_id=233?&page=2
```

On users browser url:

```
https://www.foo.com/news/article/page/2/
```

I have setup rewrite on nginx.conf like below but unsuccessful. Any idea why?

```
 location / {
    rewrite ^/article/page/([^/]+)/$ /article/pager.php?blog_id=2&tmpl_id=233&page=$1 break;
  }
```

Comment: You are rewriting to a `.php` URI, so cannot use `break` as the URI is processed by a different `location` block. Try `last`. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

Comment: I've tried 'last' but it didn't work. Server gives me 404.